# formik validation schema & initial values are not updating

Tags: reactjs, formik

formKey's state is getting changed in a child component, formKey's value is up to date in the console but the formik is not taking the updated values.

```
<Formik
          initialValues={formKey===1? initialValues: formKey===2? profileUrlsInitialValues: csvFileInitialValues}
          onSubmit={() => {}}
          validationSchema={formKey===1? addLeadsValidationSchema: formKey===2? profileUrlsValidationSchema: uploadCsvValidationSchema}
          validateOnMount
        >
```

i have tried using switch case and passing one function but it is not working, creating form's based on formKey value is not a good practice in code writing so is there something from which i can update the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a prop for that, you can use `enableReinitialize`

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean

If `initialValues` changes its value on next render, it will reset the form. The values are not copared by reference, it uses deep equality

Comment: Thank you so much, one more thing is there anything similar for validation schema also?

Comment: Not sure about this, but if you don't need the values from previous key, you might be able to reinitialize the form itself with the ```key``` prop. ```<Formik key={formKey} ... />```